# Why Is My Tidymodels Recipe Not Working When I Use Interaction Effects?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I'm working through trying to understand tidymodels and am running into an issue where my recipe won't allow interaction effects and returns an error. The code I use is this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ISLR)
data("Auto")
library(tidymodels)

auto_data <- initial_split(Auto, strata = origin)

auto_train <- training(auto_data)

auto_test <- testing(auto_data)

recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ horsepower * origin, data = auto_train)
```

And the error I get is: Error in `inline_check()`:

> ! No in-line functions should be used here; use steps to define baking
> actions. Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Why won't the recipe let me use interaction effects? I get no such error when I do:

```
recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ horsepower + origin, data = auto_train)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on `?recipe` for the formula argument:

> A model formula. No in-line functions should be used here (e.g.
> log(x), x:y, etc.) and minus signs are not allowed. These types of
> transformations should be enacted using step functions in this
> package. Dots are allowed as are simple multivariate outcome terms
> (i.e. no need for cbind; see Examples). A model formula may not be the
> best choice for high-dimensional data with many columns, because of
> problems with memory.

Note that it explicitly says not to specify interactions (`x:y`) in the formula.

In other words, the intent is for you to specify interactions explicitly with a designated `step_interaction` rather than in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_interact.html)

step_interact() creates a specification of a recipe step that will create new columns that are interaction terms between two or more variables.

step_interact should be defined outside the recipe formula.

```r
recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ horsepower + origin, data = auto_train) |> 
        step_interact(terms = ~ horsepower:origin)

recipe
#> 
#> ── Recipe ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> ── Inputs
#> Number of variables by role
#> outcome:   1
#> predictor: 2
#> 
#> ── Operations
#> • Interactions with: horsepower:origin
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>